# MySQL size in this case?

Tags: mysql

If I create a utf-8 column in MySQL and all the characters are ascii minus 1, how many characters will I be able to store?

Can someone please explain this?

Comment: Is it character or character varying?

Comment: It is TEXT or VARCHAR, not sure yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

21,844

Will be the maximum for a varchar in utf8.

It's actual chars not bytes.

[from MySQL doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-type-overview.html)

> For example, utf8 characters can require up to three bytes per
>   character, so a VARCHAR column that uses the utf8 character set can be
>   declared to be a maximum of 21,844 characters. See Section E.7.4,
>   “Limits on Table Column Count and Row Size”.
>
> MySQL stores VARCHAR values as a 1-byte or 2-byte length prefix plus
>   data. The length prefix indicates the number of bytes in the value. A
>   VARCHAR column uses one length byte if values require no more than 255
>   bytes, two length bytes if values may require more than 255 bytes.

[from Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8)

> The first 128 characters (US-ASCII) need one byte. The next 1,920
>   characters need two bytes to encode. This covers the remainder of
>   almost all Latin alphabets, and also Greek, Cyrillic, Coptic,
>   Armenian, Hebrew, Arabic, Syriac and Tāna alphabets, as well as
>   Combining Diacritical Marks. Three bytes are needed for characters in
>   the rest of the Basic Multilingual Plane (which contains virtually all
>   characters in common use[11]). Four bytes are needed for characters in
>   the other planes of Unicode, which include less common CJK characters
>   and various historic scripts and mathematical symbols.

Comment: Yes, but I mean, the ascii characters, each one will take 1 byte space or 3?